# Overflow-y: scroll and show last element when scrolled

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a simple chat. Everything is OK but when the messages reach the bottom of the container the scroll appears and hides the last element which overflows... Which is normal. I am wondering is it possible to show the last element using only CSS without JavaScript?

Comment: Your chat app i assume uses a lot of JS anyway, what difference will a couple more lines make?

Comment: BTW, i don't think you can do it with just CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use some padding or margin on the last element, then it'll show up above the height of the scrollbar at the bottom. This'll probably do the trick:

```
p:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 32px;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it only makes the scroll bigger. Is it possible to revert the scroll ? And to scroll not from the bottom end but from top ?

Comment: Now you got me puzzled, 'cause I can't see how expanding a margin, would make another thing wider. Can you add some of your code to your question? It'd make it easier to see what's going on.

Comment: I fix it! The problem was that i was applying your solution on wrong element! Thank you! :) :) :)

Comment: You're welcome :) I should've been a tad clearer I guess. I'll remember that in the future.